# encryption using Caesar Cipher with given methods..Java

Tags: java, encryption, caesar-cipher

Am trying to create a method to encrypt a word with Caesar cipher 
here is the code:

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{

    String s = "ahmed";
    int k = 2;
    char[] c = new char[5];
    int[] a = new int[s.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i<s.length();i++){

       a[i] = Secret_Code_Library.getDigit(s.charAt(i));
       a[i] = i + k ;
       c[i] = Secret_Code_Library.getLetter(a[i]);

    }                           
    String ss = String.valueOf(c);
}
```

`Secret_Code_Library` is a class that contains the two methods 
(`getDigit(char)`: returns the number of the character a =0, b= 1...etc, and 
`getLetter(int)`: returns the letter corresponding to the number).
my problem is when ever i try to encrypt a word it encrypts only
the first letter correctly and save it in to the array a.
P.S: I have to use those two methods.

the output of the above code is: **cdefg**
while it should be: **cjogf**
this is the class :

```
public class Secret_Code_Library {


public static final char [] LETTERS={'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z' };


public static char getLetter(int digit){
   return  LETTERS[digit];   }
    public static int getDigit(char ch){
    int digit=0;
    switch (ch){
        case 'A': digit=0; break;   case 'B': digit=1; break; case 'C': digit=2; break; 
        case 'D': digit=3; break;   case 'E': digit=4; break; case 'F': digit=5; break;    
        case 'G': digit=6; break;   case 'H': digit=7; break; case 'I':  digit=8; break;           
        case 'J':  digit=9; break;   case 'K': digit=10; break; case 'L': digit=11; break;    
        case 'M': digit=12; break; case 'N': digit=13; break;  case 'O': digit=14; break;    
        case 'P': digit=15; break; case 'Q': digit=16; break;   case 'R': digit=17; break;    
        case 'S': digit=18; break; case 'T': digit=19; break;   case 'U': digit=20; break;
        case 'V': digit=21; break; case 'W': digit=22; break;  case 'X': digit=23; break;    
        case 'Y': digit=24; break; case 'Z': digit=25; break;      
 }// switch
    return digit;
}}
```

Comment: so ... you want us to comment on code you won't show us?

Comment: it's not that i don't want to show you the code, but the problem is not with the methods, but i'll show the codes if it's gonna help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a[i]= i + k ;
```

should be

```
a[i] = a[i] + k;
```

because you're not adding the key to the position of the current encrypted character, but the integer value of the character itself.

But that is not enough. What happens when you're encrypting 'z' with k = 2? You should wrap around in the alphabet, if the `Secret_Code_Library.getLetter(a[i]);` doesn't already do this for you.

If your alphabet is 26 characters long, then this should do it:

```
a[i] = (a[i] + k) % 26;
```

Comment: `((a[i] - 'a' + k) % 26 + 'a')` because 'a' is 97

Comment: @WalterM Yes, that would be the case when converting the characters yourself, but OP's library does the offset for you, so that is not necessary anymore. Check the question text.

Comment: I did as you said but the output now is : CCCCC

Comment: @Ibrahim Well, of course it is. Your alphabet only contains uppercase letters, but your message only lowercase letters. None of the transformations are made. Use a uppercase message: `String s = "AHMED";` or capitalize your message `String s = "ahmed".toUpperCase();`. Keep in mind that you should also initialize `c` in a way that is as long as `s`.

Comment: thanks a lot @Artjom B 
i can't believe that i didn't notices something like that.
now i need to wrap around if user entered a word contains letter Z?

Comment: @Ibrahim You're working with numbers (indices in the alphabet array) so you can use numerical operations such as the [modulo operator `%`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).